# MismatchedInputException when using Jackson, @JsonIdentityInfo and @JsonDeserialize with a lombok Builder

Tags: java, jackson, lombok

I am trying to Serialize and Deserialize a  large object graph. In order to reduce the size of the generated JSON, I thought I would use Jackson's `@JsonIdentityInfo` annotation, which from what I can read seems to work well for this particular usecase.

However when I add that it blows up, whenever it tries to Deserialize an object it has encountered before. I'm guessing it's because I'm missing some configuration for `SimpleObjectIdResolver`, but I can't quite figure out what I'm doing wrong. Example code follows:

**Main.class**

```
@Data
@Builder
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Main.MainBuilder.class)
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class)
public class Main {

    private final String name;
    @Singular
    private final Map<String, Main> mains;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        var one = Main.builder().name("one").build();
        var test = Main.builder()
                .name("Root")
                .main("one", one)
                .main("two", Main.builder()
                        .name("two")
                        .main("one", one)
                        .build())
                .build();

        var om = new ObjectMapper();
        var result = om.writeValueAsString(test);
        System.out.println(result);
        var back = om.readValue(result, Main.class);
        System.out.println(back);
        System.out.println(back.mains.get("Two").mains.get("one") == back.mains.get("one"));
    }

    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
    public static class MainBuilder {
    }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 11
targetCompatibility = 11

mainClassName = 'dk.acto.Main'


dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.0'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.7'
    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.0"
}
```

Comment: It seems that using builders in combination with `@JsonIdentityInfo` is not supported in Jackson, see https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1496. There is a workaround in the ticket, but IMHO it's quite ugly.